# Draw phase portrait of this system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x'=xy\\
y'= -x^2.
\end{cases}
$$
I find that for this system, the line $x=0$ are a line of fixed points. I wonder how to draw the phase portrait for this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to polar coordinates:
$$
x(t)=R(t)\cos(\varphi(t))\qquad y(t)=R(t)\sin(\varphi(t))
$$
$$
x'(t)=R'(t)\cos(\varphi(t))-R(t) \varphi '(t) \sin (\varphi (t))
$$
$$
y'(t)=R'(t)\sin(\varphi(t))+R(t) \varphi '(t) \cos (\varphi (t))
$$
Then:
$$
R'(t)\cos(\varphi(t))-R(t) \varphi '(t) \sin (\varphi (t))
=R(t)^2\cos(\varphi(t))\sin(\varphi(t))
$$
$$
R'(t)\sin(\varphi(t))+R(t) \varphi '(t) \cos (\varphi (t))
=-R(t)^2\cos(\varphi(t))^2
$$
This is a linear equation for $R'(t)$ and $\varphi'(t)$, solving it yields:
$$
\begin{cases}
R'(t)=0\\
\varphi'(t)=-R(t)\cos(\varphi(t))\\
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
R'=0\\
\varphi'=-R\cos(\varphi)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $R(t)=c$, so the curves should be circles.

Using the following Mathematica code helps:

```
StreamPlot[{x y, -x^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: The curve]

([StreamPlot reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html))